# Working with proofs help?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing

I'm trying to study for my midterm and doing some random practise questions to work with proofs. However I'm stuck on, as the only way I know how to prove it is through plugging in numbers, however as I understand that is not solid proof.

Here it is:

If $x$ is a real number and $x > 0$. Prove that $$x+\frac{9}{x} \geq 6$$.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By the way, plugging in numbers does prove _something_.  But it only proves that the inequality holds for _some_ $x > 0$, rather than for _all_ $x>0$ as you are being asked to prove.  (There is a convention that the lack of a quantifier is treated as an implied "for all" quantifier.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We assume $x > 0$, start by multiplying through by $x$. (This is legitimate because in we know $x \gt 0,$ and multiplying an inequality by a positive, real number $x$, *will not change the direction of the inequality*.)

Doing so, and then gathering all terms to the left of the inequality gives us:  $$x + 9/x \geq 6 \iff x^2 + 9 \geq 6x \iff x^2 - 6x + 9 \geq 0\iff (x - 3)^2 \geq 0,$$ which is true for all real values $\,x > 0\,$ (and those are the only real values of concern) simply by virtue that *the square of a number is greater than or equal to $0$.*

$$\textrm{Hence, if}\;\,x\in \mathbb{R}, x\gt 0, \;\;\text{ then}\;\; x + \dfrac 9x \geq 6$$

Comment: @Babak thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Transform it to quadratic inequality: $x^2-6x+9\geq 0$
Solve it and you will get solution - all real numbers.

Or simply write it as square which always is equal or bigger than $0$: $(x-3)^2\geq 0$

Answer (score 0):

hint:$ax^2+bx+c \ge0 $ when $b^2-4ac\le o$ and $a\ge 0$ $$ x+\frac{9}{x}\ge 6$$ then $$x^2-6x+9\ge0$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=x+\frac {a^2}x$ where real $a>0$

$\implies x^2-xy+a^2=0 $

This is a quadratic equation in $x$ and if $x$ is real the discriminant $y^2-4\cdot1\cdot a^2$ must be $\ge0\implies y^2\ge 4a^2$

$\implies $ either $y\ge 2a$ or $y\le -2a$

If $x>0,y>0\implies y\ge2a$

We can also use calculus here

$\frac{dy}{dx}=1-\frac{a^2}{x^2}$

For the extreme values of $y,\frac{dy}{dx}=0\implies x=\pm a$

But as $x>0,x$ can not be $-a$

Now,  $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{2a^2}{x^3}>0$ as $x>0$

So, at $x=a,y$ will attain its minimum value  $a+\frac{a^2}{a}=2a$

Comment: @StackPWRequirmentsAreCrazy, how about using Quadratic Equation / Calculus?